# Issue with Macbook Pro HDMI to Denon AV receiver?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi

I'm trying to stream videos from my Mac with a high-quality HDMI cable to a 1080p HD TV via a Denon AV receiver.

Here's the issue:

When I hook up with my run-of-the-mill Windows laptop to my Denon AV receiver box, everything works perfectly.

When I hook up with my 2016 Macbook Pro, it does project the screen onto the HD TV. However, the TV screen goes black every 5 seconds, no matter what is being displayed (i.e. it blinks even when not displaying intensive graphics).

I've already reset my NVRAM. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is that the MBP with only USB-C ports? How do you connect your MBP to Denon? via some kind of USB-C to HDMI converter?

I've personally tried many different kinds of converters and have been disappointed by them. Pretty sure that's the root of your problem though. Be sure that the adapter you use does NOT support DHCP 2.2